# java.lang.NullPointerException while publishing windows azure to cloud

Tags: eclipse, azure

Im using eclipse juno-j2ee (32-bit) and apache tomcat server 6.0 (32-bit) on my laptop. I wrote simple jsp which display's hello world and packaged that project for windows azure. Now when im running that in windows azure emulator, Im able to view that on my localhost:8080/HelloWorld. But when im clicking the button publish to windows azure cloud in eclipse it started building the project and after that, it shows uploading the project at 40% for more than 1/2 hr and then it displays java.lang.NullPointerException. What's wrong with uploading? I also tried the other way by uploading the configuration and package files directly to the preview site. even it is failing after some time. How to deploy my project into the cloud? Are there any other ways?

Comment: The problem has become more worsen. Now the status 0%. I tried uploading through the management portal, there it is uploading upto 82% (which takes 2hrs time) and then displays the message "Uploading the selected package has failed, please verify your network connection and try again." which happened twice. Please help me anyone. I'm struck

Comment: Do you get a complete stack trace, or is a stack trace available *somewhere*?

Comment: No, I didn't get any stack trace

Comment: Just to make sure, you followed everything [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh690944(VS.103).aspx) told you?

Comment: Can't you see any stack trace on the Error Log view? You can find this view on "Window -> Show View -> Other...", type "error" and it may give you the option to select the view. In this view, look for the nullpointer error and double click it to open a more detailed log. There you'll may find the stack trace for your error and figure out what's going on, or post it here for helping us to help you with the error. ;-) I'm also having some troubles on a few plugins on Eclipse Juno and that's just because of interface changes on the platform.